# React.js - Unable to access values inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I've been trying to access the values inside an array of objects but for some reason when I use `console.log(quiz.questions[0].question)` I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined

code:

```js
const quizAPI = process.env.REACT_APP_API_QUIZ;

const PlayQuiz = () => {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: '',
    questions: {},
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getQuiz() {
      const param = window.location.search;
      const id = param.split('=');
      const Quiz = await axios.get(`${quizAPI}?_id=${id[1]}`);
      const { doc } = Quiz.data.data;
      console.log(doc[0]);
      const quizDoc = doc[0];
      setQuiz({ ...quiz, title: quizDoc.title, questions: quizDoc.questions });
    }
    getQuiz();
  }, []);
  console.log(quiz.questions[0].question);
```

what `console.log(quiz)` shows:

```js
{title: "findme", questions: Array(3)}
questions: Array(3)
0: {_id: "5f5500caab44c4bd2b58b109", question: "sfdf", answerSelectionOne: "sdvsv", answerSelectionTwo: "asd", answerSelectionThree: "", …}
1: {_id: "5f5500cdab44c4bd2b58b10a", question: "sfdfddd", answerSelectionOne: "sdvsv", answerSelectionTwo: "asd", answerSelectionThree: "", …}
2: {_id: "5f5500cfab44c4bd2b58b10b", question: "sfdfdddv", answerSelectionOne: "sdvsv", answerSelectionTwo: "asd", answerSelectionThree: "", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
title: "findme"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the quiz field values correctly it is recommended to use another useEffect that watches the `quiz` state :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        
        if(quiz.questions.length){
           console.log(quiz.questions[0].question);
         }
        
    }, [quiz]);
```

Comment: A second useEffect makes alot of sense and will help further on. Thank you,

Comment: Yes it's useful to give your data some flow during the component life cycle

Answer (score 2):

Usually this means you are trying to access a property on a possibly `null` or `undefined` variable.

Probably you need to change the initial `useState` first because `questions` is an array and not an object `{}` as the following:

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: '',
    questions: [],
});
```

Secondly `quiz.questions` can have `length` of `0`. So with a simple check before like `quiz.questions.length > 0` you can eliminate that issue.

Then you can use logging as:

```
console.log(quiz.questions.length > 0 ? quiz.questions[0].question : null);
```

Comment: Yes checking the length makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are trying to use an object {} as an array []!

What Javascript is trying to do is access this:

```
{
 "0" : { // your data},
}
```

What it should look like:

```
[
 0 : { // your data},
]
```

What you want to change is :

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: '',
    questions: [], // make it an array
});
```

And possibly consider using .push() to push individual objects to an array